Why doesn't FlushAsync() exist on Kafka Client API?
We know that calling the flush() blocks the current thread until all the pending messages in the queue are sent.
But why there is no flushAsync() on Java or .NET Kafka API Client?
Frrom the docs
we can see that there is only flush().
Obviously we don't want the current thread to be blocked for some time, so we want to have the benefits of async programming. We want to let the current thread go back to the thread pool to execute other tasks and later let another worker thread continue.

How would you envisage using flushAsync?

On Java, you can use another thread. You can use CompletableFuture or Thread.
Example:
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    provider.flush();
});
Thread.ofVirtual().start(() -> provider.flush()); // from doc

// in another way:
new Thread(provider::flush).start();

All of those example create a new thread that let the main one be safe.
